# How to efficiently filter maximum elements of a matrix per row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

Given a 2D array, I'm looking for a pythonic way to get an array of same shape, with only the maximum element per each row. 
See max_row_filter function below

```
def max_row_filter(mat2d):
    m = np.zeros(mat2d.shape)
    for r in range(mat2d.shape[0]):
        c = np.argmax(mat2d[r])
        m[r,c]=mat2d[r,c]
    return m

p = np.array([[1,2,3],[5,4,3,],[9,10,3]])
max_row_filter(p)

Out: array([[ 0.,  0.,  3.],
            [ 5.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0., 10.,  0.]])
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this, suitable to be done on big arrays.

Comment: What if there are duplicates of the max value per row?

Comment: For my application I'd prefer to have a single value in a row, so argmax based solutions are fine. Anyway in reality the values are real numbers very unlikley to be exactly equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative answer (this will keep duplicates):

```
p * (p==p.max(axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicates, you could use [numpy.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [5, 4, 3, ],
              [9, 10, 3]])

result = np.zeros_like(p)

rows, cols = zip(*enumerate(np.argmax(p, axis=1)))
result[rows, cols] = p[rows, cols]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 0  0  3]
 [ 5  0  0]
 [ 0 10  0]]
```

Note that, for multiple occurrences argmax return the first occurence.